# Of what type should I make a dependency property in my custom control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, custom-controls, dependency-properties, itemssource

I have a wpf user control that acts as a data navigator for forms (ie go to the first, last, previous or next records or add and save a record).  In common with many things the more I've learnt about wpf the more I've come to appreciate that whilst this works it lacks finesse (indeed it lacks a lot of basics in truth!) and could really do with improving.  Because it's the sort of thing that I would use a lot I'd like to turn it into a custom control, which in turn should give me the chance to learn more about wpf custom controls in general.

So to the question.  When I add this custom control to a view in one of my applications I'll want to bind it to whatever data source that that view's viewmodel is providing.  Whilst I generally use the entity framework (and very specifically component one's LiveLinq to create my data sources) I would like this control to be more generic and allow me to add a datasource from different sources.  So I envisage that it should have either an ItemsSource or DataSource property (which would obviously be a dependency property (and I guess the name is academic , or perhaps not?)) but the question is to make it as generic as possible of what type should I make this property?

I'm inclining towards Object and then casting that to either a CollectionView or EditableCollectionView in an overridden initialize sub but in truth I really can't determine what would be best and therefore which way I ought to go.  I'd welcome any advice that can be proffered.

Comment: This sounds a good job for the Selector class. It already has number of important built-in properties. If you are envisioning other properties that is not present in Listbox, Combobox and other Selector derivatives, that is the time you have to think of other types.

Comment: @tagaPdyk  Thank you for your suggestion.  I've just looked up the documentation on Selector and noticed that it is related to itemscontrol (obviously adding the ability to deal with selections.  Given that I solely want to be able to navigate through the collection (and possibly add a new item to it would it perhaps make more sense to go with ItemsControl?  Unfortunately this is new territory to me so I'm still finding my way around it.

Comment: Off the shelf, you can actually use ItemsControl without any customization. And I feel that the requirements you have mentioned can be done by ItemsControl. However, if you want to support the ability to check the "selected" item from your CollectionView, the Selector can give you more. And if you also notice, Selector is an abstract class, so you have a chance to have fun sub-classing as I feel you are up to the challenge. Other than that, ItemsControl is fine.

Comment: @tagaPdyk  Many thanks.  Given that this is still new territory to me ItemsControl sounds like a good place to start.  As knowledge and confidence grows then hopefully I can explore further.